# Oracle SQL script to build SQL script using dbms_output

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, dbms-output

This may be a stupid idea.  I am trying to write a SQL*Plus .sql script that I can call from a Windows batch file that itself generates a new .sql script using dbms_output.put_line.  This is what I have so far for my script:

```
set echo off;
set serverout on;

conn user@pass;

spool E:\new_script.sql

DECLARE

  CURSOR c_groups IS
    SELECT * FROM table;

  s varchar2(4000);

BEGIN

  dbms_output.put_line('BEGIN');

  FOR x IN c_groups LOOP
    s := 'INSERT INTO TABLE blah VALUES ('''||x.name||''','||x.id||');';
  END LOOP;

  dbms_output.put_line(s);

  dbms_output.put_line('COMMIT;');

  dbms_output.put_line('END;');
  dbms_output.put_line('/');

END;
/

spool off;
exit;
```

However, when I do this, my `new_script.sql` just says *"PL/SQL procedure successfully completed."*  Any ideas how to make the `dbms_out.put_line` actually display their message?

And I'm not actually doing this to build insert statements - those are just a simple sample showing the gist of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

1. You have to connect first and then use `SET` command. So your three commands should be in

   this order:

   ```
   conn user@pass;
   set echo off;
   set serverout on;
   ```

   Otherwise, `serveroutput` parameter will be set to its default

   value, which is `OFF` and that the reason why `dbms_output.put_line()`

   hasn't been working as expected.
2. You should execute  `dbms_output.put_line(s)` inside the `FOR` loop:

   ```
   FOR x IN c_groups LOOP
      s := 'INSERT INTO TABLE blah VALUES ('''||x.name||''','||x.id||');';
      dbms_output.put_line(s);
   END LOOP;
   ```

   Moreover it's redundant to *spool* `BEGIN .. END`  block. The  DML statements

   (bunch of `INSERT INTO` statements in this case) terminated by semicolon will be

   executed just fine without being included in the `BEGIN END` block.
3. As you run your script using `*.bat` file, It probably will be useful to use the

   following commands:

   ```
   set feedback off;  -- To not spool messages like 
                      -- PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

   set termout off;   -- to suppress the output from a command line.
   ```
4. Your approach could probably be boiled down to a simple `SELECT` statement:

   ```
   conn user@pass;

   set echo off;
   set serverout on;
   set feedback off;
   set termout off;
   set heading off;

   spool E:\new_script.sql

   SELECT 'INSERT INTO TABLE blah VALUES ('''||name||'''','||to_char(id)||');'
    FROM table;

   spool off;

   exit;
   ```

Comment: +1 But adding the `BEGIN` and `END;` may be a very good idea.  On a slow network, processing one PL/SQL block will be significantly faster than processing many SQL statements.  Although that approach will generate `DIANA` errors if the PL/SQL block is ginormous.

Comment: 1) I don't think it matters whether you CONN before or after SET. My SET ECHO ON was working in both places.
2) In real life, the dbms_output call was inside the loop; that was a transcription error.  Also, the inside of my loop involves function calls that set a variable, so that is why I had the BEGIN and END in there.
3) Those would be useful, thanks.
4) This goes back to #2, in that I was going more processing within the loop.

I probably could have done without the anonymous BEGIN..END block wrapping the whole thing. I ended up using UTL_FILE though, but thanks for looking at it.

Comment: @Tom It does matter for `serveroutput` parameter. It doesn't matter for `echo` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

[`SPOOL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve043.htm#SQPUG126) sends the results to a file; but it doesn't ensure that results are printed. To enable the printing to stdout; use the [`SERVEROUTPUT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_eight.htm#sthref954) command.

```
set serveroutput on
```

This is generally a poor way of going about things; I recognise that you said this wasn't what you're actually doing but SQL is a set based language. Do things in bulk if at all possible.